# Cordova 3.3.0 + jqueryMobile 1.4.0 Transitions not working

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Recently i upgraded to jquerymobile 1.4 and it seems that the default page transitions are not working with cordova 3.3.0 anymore. They were working when i was using jqueryMobile 1.3.2.

The transitions work perfectly in a browser but when i test it on a cordova app on an android 4.x phone( on which it should technically work) they aren't working.

**Note**: I noticed that the very first page transition works, but then it stops working. Anyone experiencing the same thing ?

example code that i tested :

```
<html>

  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>

  <div data-role="page" id="homepage" >

    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Homepage</h1>
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <h2>content</h2>
      <a href="#page2" data-transition="slide">Page 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="page" id="page2">

    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Homepage</h1>
    </div>

      <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <a href="#homepage" data-transition="slide">HomePage</a>

      </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-conten">

    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue in jquery mobile 1.4.1, but it works well again with version 1.4.2. Greetings

Comment: I can't get page transitions working, I have cordova 3.6.4 and jquery mobile 1.4.2..